# How to remove '\' symbol from a string in PYTHON

Tags: python

```
new_filename_name = new_filename_name.remove("\")
```

How can I use '\' symbol normally in python?
no matter how I use this symbol it interprets it as a command like \n.

Comment: By escaping it `\\ `!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say to interpreter (python) for escaping the symbol by adding this symbol -->   `\\`

so your syntax be like this:

```
new_filename_name = new_filename_name.remove("\\")
```

It same as ignoring another symbol:

```
"\\n" --> for escaping the \n
```

[example escaping the \n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChFJQ.png)

Comment: OP brought it up, but it's worth mentioning the `str.remove` does not exist. The correct way to do this would be `new_file_name.replace('\\', '')`

Comment: sorry, it was wrong I didn't pay attention to the data type.
thank you for correcting me